# How to use a variable inside the IDE control properties?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

I'm in a WinForm project and I have this var in the declarations of my main form:

> Dim Game_Color As Color = Color.FromArgb(97, 31, 28)

Then is it possibly to use the variable in the IDE, here?

[image]

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variable in the `Designer`, but you can in the `code`. So set the Color in your code. I think you want to take a look at the `TextBox Events`, you should change the Color under the desired `Event`. For Example OnTextChanged:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Change color here
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

You could change the TextBox Color in here:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Change Color here
     TextBox_Game.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(97, 31, 28)
End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou, but  I can do it with a variable that contains a normal color? or for example a RGB string like this: "97;31;28" like the string when we use RGB color in the designer.

Comment: No, is not possible, you can set the color, but you can't do that using a variable declared in your code.

Comment: Then any solution? I can't use a public property or something instead a variable?

Comment: You could change the color on the Load event of your form. The Form load will be called when the Form opens.

Comment: I know, but what I wanted to do that when loading the designer, will set the values ​​of the properties from my code somehow either variables or otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want another background color for your TextBox when the Designer is loading?

Comment: I will mean for example: make a new project, drop a textbox in the designer, then set a variable (or something) in the code that contains a color (QB or RGB), and then a way to use that custom color in the designer property of the control (for example "backcolor" property), then if I'll reload the project, I will see the textbox backcolor with my custom color property instead of the default color of the control.

Comment: No, it isn't possible to use the variable declared in the code in the designer, best way to modify properties of controls, is to do this by the code.

Comment: No problem, that is what StackOverFlow is for:) just comment on this topic when you have move questions about it.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
string strCol = "97-31-28";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox_Game.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt16(strCol.Split('-')[0]), Convert.ToInt16(strCol.Split('-')[1]), Convert.ToInt16(strCol.Split('-')[2]));
}
```

It's C#, but you can easily convert it to VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks but that not do the trick... your code is for changging the color at execution time, I'm looking to change the color at designer without manual typing the value in the property field (for example writing a variable in the code and tell the designer to take that value and use it in the property field) , thanks anyway

Comment: I see, well you simply can't set those values from a variable, because the Designer will be frequently updated (each time you modify the GUI structure), so it will automatically convert those variables as constant numbers, no matter where you get them... Btw, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Cause I'm lazy to manual set the property of a big amount of controls in the designer, I was hope this can be donde with a code-way trick but seems not... thanks!